# Adding ads to android code using admob

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, admob

Eclipse gives the following error when i try to ad ads to my application.

The following classes could not be found: 
- com.google.ads.Adview (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Manifest :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
  <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<com.google.ads.Adview
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitID="MYID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.Adview>
```

I have checked my code thousand times i think there is no mistake in the manifest or in the xml. 
Please help me

Also when i try to do so by using java i was'nt able to import com.google.android.gms.ads.*

Comment: Did you add the admob to your project? If no, then there are ton of tutorial, blogs explaining how to add admob sdk to your project.Hard work always pays so do a bit.

Comment: yes i added it, I have downloaded the google mobile ads sdk also i have added external jar file of the googleadmobsdk-6.4.1

Comment: @user3180980I think there is problem with space for your Adview. Is this your only one and main layout? Find in your logcat information from admob/adview - you will see what's is goin on wrong.

Comment: No i have more layouts, and this the main one. Well i have a splash screen first and then after it this layout shows. But i have only added ads to this layout only

Comment: ok try to change the minsdk version to 14 within manifest.

Comment: or try change `BANNER` to `ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"`. No I am talking about space for your Adview. It must have own space. There is the minimum value of space for it. It there is not space it won't show up.

Comment: still the same for both..:(

Comment: can you run app anyway? did you add dependencies?

Comment: no the app wont run it crashes after the splash screen i.e when this layout shows up. I am sorry but i am newbie what are dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Copy AdMob lib file (**GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar**) to your **libs folder**, so Eclipse will automatically include it to your build.
And also **add** the library to **project’s build path**.

More info here:

http://jimmod.com/blog/2012/07/jimmys-blog-adding-admobs-ads-to-android-application/